# how to create a standalone grails app with h2 db by using standalone plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin

I am using grails standalone plugin to create a standalone grails app but I am getting a jdbc h2 exception. It seems to be that the database is not created at runtime.

How can I solve this issue?

Here the exception

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "COMPANY" not found; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id15_0_, this_.version as version15_0_, this_.name as name15_0_ from company this_ limit ? [42102-164]

    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)

    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)

    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4753)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1080)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1686)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1793)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1680)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1523)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1511)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:405)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)

    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:217)

    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)

    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)

    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1121)

    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:71)

    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:267)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)

    at grails.orm.PagedResultList.<init>(PagedResultList.java:55)

    at com.kodigon.sensexplorer.survey.CompanyController.list(CompanyController.groovy:19)

    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)

    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)

    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)

    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)

    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)

    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)

    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:380)

    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)

    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 1):

H2 will create the database, it just might not be creating the schema you're expecting.  You can add something the following to your URL in DataSource.groovy:

```
INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST
```

So you'd have something like:

```
url = jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I am using url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS testDb" but it did not work

Answer (score -1):

While a little bit old it can help others in the future,
In my case it was only that there were no changelog included, so after a research

Link that helped a lot to understand the issue I had that look similar
[how to create a standalone grails app with h2 db by using standalone plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612362/how-to-create-a-standalone-grails-app-with-h2-db-by-using-standalone-plugin)

Said that, I created a new one and included the generated migration and it worked like a charm...